# Spark : how to apply filter on only part of dataset?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a `dataset` like following :

```
name | gender | age |
Kirito | Male | 17 |
Eugeo | Male | 15  |
Asuna | Female | 16 |
Alice | Female | 15 |
```

In the filtered result, I want to have **(all males) joins (all females whose age is under 16)** (so the returned rows should only have `Kirito, Eugeo and Alice`), how I can do this filter ?

Comment: What about trying a first attempt - as Tech Lead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
dataset.filter((dataset.gender=='Male') | ((dataset.gender=='Female') & (dataset.age<16)).show()
```

Comment: Hi, yes this will work. But I want to know if there is better ways, because in other scenarios, I cannot just say (dataset.gender=='Male'), because "gender" will have many values.

Comment: Hi @TechLead In case if there is long list then you can try isin(list) function.